# Font awesome icon stack doesn't quite work when i try to make the stack larger

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

im doing the following design at the moment:

[image]

The circle might look okay on this picture, but its really too small seen in the larger design, so i would like to make it larger, this is my current code:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x course-status-icon">
     <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <strong class="fa-stack-1x circle-text">
           Done!
     </strong>
</span>
```

Now the sensible thing to make it bigger would be something like:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x course-status-icon">
         <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-3x"></i>
         <strong class="fa-stack-2x circle-text">
               Done!
         </strong>
    </span>
```

But that doesn't work out AT ALL, so im looking for a little bit of help :) i have made a fiddle for my situation and added some of my current css and some test markup: 
[jsfiddle to make it easier to help](https://jsfiddle.net/7LxwjLwr/)

Thanks alot!

Comment: If all you are doing is making colored circles, font-awesome seems unnecessary. - https://jsfiddle.net/7LxwjLwr/2/

Comment: Yeah that might be true, i just couldn't put together how i would make sure that the text was allways in the middle of the circle, and font-awesome had a finished solution. Thanks alot for the input though, maybe il feel confident enough to it my self next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of your circle, or even the text inside the circle, just change the font-size for that element's selector (in this case, fa-circle)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/7LxwjLwr/3/

```
i.circle-text {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: It was the circles size i was looking for, thanks for taking the time to look it over.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change the fa fa icon size i mentioned it on the snap]

Change the fa fa icon size i mentioned it on the snap

Answer (score 0):

Keep the size of the circle and text but make the span 5x instead of lg.

```
    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x course-status-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
       <strong class="fa-stack-1x circle-text">
       Done!
       </strong>
   </span>
```

I've encountered this issue myself before and tried to change the size of the stacked icons but that just throws everything off for some reason and changing the span worked for me. Hope it helps!